# XMPP One To One Chat in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xmpp, ejabberd

I am getting "userid is nill" and sent message is not storing when switching to another viewcontroller. I want to implement XMPP One to One chat, how can I do this?

I have full project with me now but it is in nib files; my work is to convert that in to storyboards. I have done almost but I am getting stuck at XMPP.

What methods I have to use am getting stuck with some errors like "userid is nill".

Comment: if any one have the code send me urgent if some one can help me i will send the all code to you

Comment: I understand that all code is included in the project but when chatting previous message are not storing in to database

Comment: Which XMPP server are you using? If its [ejabberd](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu) there is facility to store all chat message on MySQL database and later using separate webservice you may get chat history from DB.

Comment: i dont now much about this framework i did not even work before am stuck with this going to loose my job

Comment: Don't worry, check my answer below. :)

Comment: Hi Mahesh. Just so you know, requests to send the code to someone helping are generally discouraged here - the idea with questions is that they contain pretty much everything one would need to understand the problem and supply an answer. If it is not possible to create such a question for a particular case, it is probably that the problem is too broad, and it needs to be broken down (which does seem to apply in this case).

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in comment that you are using ejabberd XMPP server. There is a module [mod_logdb](https://www.ejabberd.im/mod_logdb) which can store chat log to database.

Following is sample of configuration, just to have a look how you can configure mysql db to work with ejabberd.

```
{modules, [

  {mod_logdb, [
    {dbs, [
      {mysql5, [
        {user, "root"},
        {password, "pass"},
        {server, "serv"},
        {port, 3306},
        {db, "logdb"}
      ]},
      {mnesia, []}
    ]},
    {vhosts, [{"example1.org", mysql5}, {"example2.org", mnesia}{purge_older_days, 365},
    {dolog_default, true},
    {poll_users_settings, 5}   ]},
     %% Other modules ...
]}.
```

It will store all chat history/log to Database given in config file, from where you can read it as a normal MySQL query and pass to your application via webservice.

Reference Links:

1. [mod_logdb](https://www.ejabberd.im/mod_logdb?)
2. [Configuration guide](http://www.dp.uz.gov.ua/o.palij/mod_logdb/)

Comment: Dude, This should be configured on your server, where your XMPP is installed (Linux or windows server). In iOS there's nothing to do, you just have to use one webservice e.g. `get_chat_log.php` (whatever server language you do prefer) which will read chat-log from MySQL database and output in JSON/XML to your iOS application. Then you can populate those chat messages to your chat screen on your application. Hope its clear.

Comment: @Mahesh04 If, configuring server isn't on your hand you might just ask server people to install mentioned module and ask them to configure it. Its very easy.

Comment: Yaa it is clear now i came to now that i have to use api's to get chat log

Comment: Yes, exactly. You might want to look at [this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911210/ejabberd-retrieve-chat-history-from-mysql-db)